# Large SQL database removing duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates, sql-delete

Large SQL 2008 table with 60 000 000 records, and I have problem with duplicate rows.

This command gives me my duplicate taken from
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444

```
SELECT     id, sa_trvalue,  COUNT(*) AS tot  
FROM         msanal   
GROUP BY id, sa_trvalue  
HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

But when I follow through the steps (INTO and DISTINCT) I get not enough memory to complete operation.

Comment: If you really need to create a new table with no duplicates, an easy way would be to restrict the query with Where Id >= 0 and Id < 100000 and then just page through until you've covered the entire range. To just get rid, Mr Schmelter has given you a way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach which might need less memory:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  id, sa_trvalue, 
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, sa_trvalue ORDER BY id ASC)
    FROM    msanal   
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE rn > 1
```

A common table expression has also the advantage that you can modify it easily to see what you are going to delete. Therefore you just have to change `DELETE` to `SELECT *`.

Comment: You don't really need to select `id, sa_trvalue` inside of CTE?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: No, just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete msanal from msanal m1
where exists
(select null from msanal m2
where m2.sa_trvalue = m1.sa_trvalue and m2.id <> m1.id)
```